# Can I use T extends Contravariant<any> to safely constrain generic type to a Contravariant union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's start with some definitions:

```
type Contravariant<T> = (t: T) => void;
declare let cNum: Contravariant<number>;
declare let cStr: Contravariant<string>;
```

Now, say I want to make a function which I can pass in an array of `Contravariant` union type. First, I used a simple approach:

```
declare function f1<T>(a: T[]): void;
f1([cNum, cStr]); // T inferred as 'Contravariant<number> | Contravariant<string>'
```

Looks good! However, the array can take any type currently, I'd like to limit this to only `Contravariant` type, so let's make `T` extend `Contravariant`.

```
declare function f2<T extends Contravariant<any>>(a: T[]): void;
f2([cNum, cStr]); // T inferred as 'Contravariant<number> | Contravariant<string>'
```

Seems to work good. However, eslint is now complaining about using `any`. `unknown` obviously doesn't work since it's contravariant.

What are the potential downsides to using `any` in this case? Can I safely use `any`? Are there any ways to do this without using `any`?

Some other things I tried:

```
declare function f3<T extends Contravariant<U>, U>(a: T[]): void;
f3([cNum, cStr]);
// Type 'Contravariant<number>' is not assignable to type 'Contravariant<unknown>'.
//  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

```
declare function f3a<U>(a: Contravariant<U>[]): void;
f3a([cNum, cStr]);
// Type 'Contravariant<string>' is not assignable to type 'Contravariant<number>'.
//   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

```
declare function f4<T extends Contravariant<T extends Contravariant<infer I> ? I : never>>(a: T[]): void;
f4([cNum, cStr]);
// Type 'Contravariant<string>' is not assignable to type 'Contravariant<string | number>'.
//   Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why do all these (f3, f3a, f4) result in a different type inferred? They look like they all do the same thing to me.

Comment: I guess this is not such a good pattern all in all. TS is making this so difficult, because the type you're trying to get (`Contravariant<string | number>[]`) can't really be worked with. Imagine you have such an array, and now do this: `contravariantArray[7]('hoho')`. How in the world should TypeScript tell if this is okay or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any downside of using `any` here. After all, it's just used for a constraint. But if you really need a solution without `any`, you may be interested in this:

```
declare function f1<
  T extends unknown[]
>(a: [...{ [K in keyof T]: Contravariant<T[K]> }]): void;

f1([cNum, cStr]);
```

`T` will be inferred as `[number, string]` in this case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=18&pln=9&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYgE4EMBu7UEt0oA8AKgHwwC8MAFCAFwzECUl5mCuAJgNzCdQBjADY5YQqCBgCAcgFcAtg0QoM2PARCEkCgEZRUpXv2GiY4yQIDKaJcjRYc%20IgGc0uJAHNDwHz%20MjUWAAzWSQBEFxkGCCARkJgGEYYKAAPECgkTmcYUIBrJAQAdyQAbQBdYFJqdAYSgDoGgG8YEoBpGHcYXKgwBCDGMtsVB3UiYjay8gBfMqYGdi5eYFjqEpkFABopa1RZ3iA)